# Max theoretical efficiency of a weight powering a car

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation

Say we had a 700 gram car. There is a 2 kg weight on a launcher that is supposed to power it. What is the maximum theoretical speed it takes to travel 8 meters?

Its a little hard to describe so here's a diagram of it:

[A diagram of the launcher](http://scioly.org/wiki/images/5/54/SC-pulleytype.gif)

Comment: It all depends on the rolling resistance of the car. Only you can find out what launch velocity will get you that far. 8m doesn't sound like much of a challenge. I can see this thing doing 80m on the right surface and with the right wheels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess they can be seen as
$$m_{_w}*g-T=m_{_w}*a;$$
$$T=m_{_c}*a$$
$$a=({m_{_w}*g})/(m_{_w}+m_{_c})$$
$$V={\sqrt (2*d*a)}$$
As @CuriousOne has mentioned it depends on the rolling resistance and it seems like 8 mts is no big deal for this.